# SVN - Update branch with changes from trunk in Cornerstone 2

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging, cornerstone

Is there any way from Cornerstone 2's UI to update a branch with changes made in the trunk after the branch was created?

Comment: The SVN keyword here is "merge". You want to merge the trunk into your branch. With the CLI, it is simply: `svn co $REPO/branch/foo;  svn merge -r $REV_RANG $REPO/trunk .; svn commit`. Sorry I can't help you with your GUI thing, but theoretically it should be the same procedure.

Comment: So then merging the trunk into the branch would only attempt to merge the updated files and not the entire trunk?

Comment: Depends on $REV_RANGE. You select the revisions with the changes you want to merge. If you want to merge all changes, use the revision you branched on and HEAD (e.g. 1527:HEAD). Otherwise, select revisions you want merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. In the working copy, I selected the branch's root directory and clicked 'Merge' from Cornerstone's top toolbar. From the merge interface, the 'Synchronize Branch' option is selected, and Cornerstone performs a "dry run" of the merge and displays a preview of all the files it will merge in from the trunk (there is a 'Merge From' box that defaults to the root trunk directory, ^/trunk). From here just clicked "Merge Changes" and branch was updated with all the changed files.